# Formatting Material Table Pagination and Filter

Tags: angular, user-interface

Hi I am using Angular Material tables(all functional with no issues) and would like to make some changes to the default functionality for the Pagination and the Filter. I can't figure out if there are directives/functions within the Material tables or I have to add it separately ?
html

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="panel panel-red">
                <div class="panel-heading">To Do List</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <mat-form-field>
                        <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
                    </mat-form-field>
                    <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
                        <ng-container matColumnDef="Comment">
                            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Commment </mat-header-cell>
                            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.Comment}} </mat-cell>
                        </ng-container>
                        <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns" ></mat-header-row>
                        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns:displayedColumns"></mat-row>
                    </mat-table>
                    <mat-paginator #paginator
                                   [pageSize]="10"
                                   [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" >
                    </mat-paginator>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

component.ts

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
    dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
    @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
    @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;


    displayedColumns = ['Comment'];

     ngOnInit(): void {

        console.log("id : " + this.userID)
        this.GetUserLocations(this.userID)
        this.getBSAFollowup();
        this.GetToDoList(this.userID);

        //this.dataSource = this.toDoList;
    }
    onOpen() {

        this._dashboardService.delBSAFollowup(this.selectedRowID).subscribe(() => {
          //  this.showMessage('File has been uploaded successfully!', 'alert alert-success');
           this.getBSAFollowup();

        },
          error => console.log('Upload File: '));

    }

    GetToDoList(ID: string) {
        this._dashboardService.getToDoList(ID)
            .subscribe(
            data => {
              //  this.toDoList = data.result;
                //this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data.result);
                this.dataSource.data = data.result;
                  },
            error => console.log('GetControls Method: ' + <any>error, 'alert alert-danger'));
    }

     ngAfterViewInit() {

        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    }
    applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
        filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
        filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); // MatTableDataSource defaults to lowercase matches
        this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
    }

}
```

here is how it looks
[image]
I would like to add numbers between the two brackets so some thing like this 
[image]

Also the filter in top it needs to be stretched out to cover the entire grid

***************************************UPDATE**************************************************************

I was able to change the Filter widh to 100%...to cover the width of the grid real estate.

```
 <mat-form-field style="width:100%">
                        <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
                    </mat-form-field>
```

Now I need to figure how to add number pagination

Comment: I was able to do this "extend the filter in top it needs, to be stretched out to cover the entire grid"..now I just to figure out if Material supports number pagination